# Problems compiling Halide's camera_pipe application on Mac OS

Tags: c++, x86-64, halide

I'm new to Halide and just successfully compiled Halide from source. I wanted to try out the camera_pipe application from the source code (https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/apps/camera_pipe), but I'm getting the following error, and I'm not sure how to debug / fix it. Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help!

My system is running Mac OS Sierrar (10.12.3)

This is command that the Makefile ran:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -I ../../include/ -I ../../tools/ -I ../../apps/support/ -g -fno-rtti camera_pipe_generator.cpp ../../lib/libHalide.a ../../tools/GenGen.cpp -o bin/camera_pipe_exec -L/usr/local/lib -ldl -lpthread -lz
```

And this is the error output that I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_del_curterm", referenced from:
          llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libHalide.a(llvm_460_Process.cpp.o)
      "_set_curterm", referenced from:
          llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libHalide.a(llvm_460_Process.cpp.o)
      "_setupterm", referenced from:
          llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libHalide.a(llvm_460_Process.cpp.o)
      "_tigetnum", referenced from:
          llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libHalide.a(llvm_460_Process.cpp.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [bin/camera_pipe_exec] Error 1
```

Comment: Where did `../../lib/libHalide.a` come from?  Did you build it, too?  With the same toolchain?

Comment: I think I built it when I ran "make" from the halide directory (https://github.com/halide/Halide), and it did compile without errors there. And I think it was with the same toolchain.

Comment: Update: I re-ran "make-clean" and "make", so I'm certain it is with the same toolchain now. However, I am still getting that same error. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your llvm depends on terminfo, but the camera pipe doesn't link it by default. Try adding a -ltinfo into the makefile along with -lpthread -lz, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have tinfo installed and I'm not sure where to get it, but I tried replacing it with -lcurses, and got the following error instead: `ld: file too small (length=0) file 'bin/Demosaic.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: This is the current Makefile command: `c++ -std=c++11 -I ../../include/ -I ../../tools/ -I ../../apps/support/ -Wall -O3 -I./bin process.cpp bin/camera_pipe.a bin/Demosaic.o bin/Demosaic_ARM.o -o bin/process -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.28/lib -lpng16 -ljpeg -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.28/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.28/include/libpng16/.. -lcurses -L/usr/local/lib -ldl -lpthread -lz`

Comment: Sorry, but is there something I could do to fix that error?

Comment: Never mind, I did a "make clean" and then "make" and that fixed it! Thank you!